# Can "... and have been ..." be replaced by "..., having been ..."?

Tags: punctuation

"I'm an enthusiastic learner and have been partaking in various scientific events."

If I'd like to replace the "and" with a comma, is the following new sentence consider correct?

"I'm an enthusiastic learner, having been partaking in various scientific events."

Comment: Yes, but the meaning changes. The "and have been" sentence shows that you are both an enthusiastic learner and that you have participated in the events. The "having been" sentence implies that you are an enthusiastic learner _because_ you have partaken in the events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right, a "comma" can be added, "and" can be omitted, but I would say:

"I'm an enthusiastic learner, **having participated** in several scientific events."

"partake" doesn't sound like current usage.

Answer (score 1):

"taking part in" would be ok as well; it means to participate. But "partaking" in modern usage connotes consuming something, usually food or drink.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, the second option is grammatically correct too.

Although it is technically correct, the phrase "having been partaking" is awkward. If you were looking for clarity, I would suggest this upgrade:

"As an enthusiastic learner, I have been partaking in various scientific events."

If you wanted to go over the top, you could change "partaking" to "participating" as @Centaurus suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Is "taking part in several scientific events" intended as evidence of being an enthusiastic learner? If so, your substitution is perfectly reasonable. But if the two are unconnected (or correlated but not causatively), you really need to have a conjunction between them, if not a full stop.